# changing the color of a shirt image

Tags: css

I would like to know how I can change the color of a shirt image without having to take a lot of pictures. I have seen on this website
 https://www.shirtspace.com/product/2021-jerzees-29m-5-6-oz-50-50-heavyweight-blend-t-shirt?variant_id=8935
that you can change the color of the shirt and the image looks exactly the same except for the shirt color the man on the images looks to be in the same exact position every time.  where can I get images like this without getting in trouble of copy write.

Comment: The images in the link are different :/

Comment: so all they changed was the face? to make it identical

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If your look for making identical images except with a different colored shirt you could do it in a image editing software. Personal I like to use GIMP Image Editor. You could use a fill bucket tool or paint with a partly transparent color.

Comment: I want to change the color of shirts. thank you ill give it a try

Comment: would I get in trouble if I copy the images and just erase the body?